# php: how to get my all uploaded videos details from my vimeo account based api key

Tags: php, video, vimeo

I am working now vimeo api. I have created vimeo api account from this link
https://developer.vimeo.com/.And i also have uploaded multi videos in my vimeo account. Now i want get my uploaded all videos details from my vimeo account based mu api key used my php language. I tried many link.I have to just tried this link
https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib. But i got issue. My index file is there .I have to change only index file to update only my api keys.

```
<?php
        require_once('vimeo.php');
        session_start();

        // Create the object and enable caching
        $vimeo = new phpVimeo('6418f15fd14988bd412f28e7fdec6a573ad3e4df', 'OiqPWf1W+eLoPioLsJ4Fe2Im7DyFlEDT8zv6c15kqQjxoV0SgJatMzRp+h4bKXWD+ChBYdehRQLxRiNYVSZxnZTohmkzVLVj5JrCtwNwoxNCyK+qWpGLcJs5aN5JMOKT');
        $vimeo->enableCache(phpVimeo::CACHE_FILE, './cache', 300);

        // Clear session
        if ($_GET['clear'] == 'all') {
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
        }

        // Set up variables
        $state = $_SESSION['vimeo_state'];
        $request_token = $_SESSION['oauth_request_token'];
        $access_token = $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'];

        // Coming back
        if ($_REQUEST['oauth_token'] != NULL && $_SESSION['vimeo_state'] === 'start') {
        $_SESSION['vimeo_state'] = $state = 'returned';
        }

        // If we have an access token, set it
        if ($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] != null) {
        $vimeo->setToken($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_access_token_secret']);
        }

        switch ($_SESSION['vimeo_state']) {
        default:

        // Get a new request token
        $token = $vimeo->getRequestToken();

        // Store it in the session
        $_SESSION['oauth_request_token'] = $token['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_request_token_secret'] = $token['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['vimeo_state'] = 'start';

        // Build authorize link
        $authorize_link = $vimeo->getAuthorizeUrl($token['oauth_token'], 'write');

        break;

        case 'returned':

        // Store it
        if ($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] === NULL && $_SESSION['oauth_access_token_secret'] === NULL) {
        // Exchange for an access token
        $vimeo->setToken($_SESSION['oauth_request_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_request_token_secret']);
        $token = $vimeo->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

        // Store
        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token'] = $token['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_access_token_secret'] = $token['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['vimeo_state'] = 'done';

        // Set the token
        $vimeo->setToken($_SESSION['oauth_access_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_access_token_secret']);
        }

        // Do an authenticated call
        try {
        $videos = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.getUploaded');
        }
        catch (VimeoAPIException $e) {
        echo "Encountered an API error -- code {$e->getCode()} - {$e->getMessage()}";
        }

        break;
        }

        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Vimeo Advanced API OAuth Example</title>
        </head>
        <body>

        <h1>Vimeo Advanced API OAuth Example</h1>
        <p>This is a basic example of Vimeo's new OAuth authentication method. Everything is saved in session vars, so <a href="?clear=all">click here if you want to start over</a>.</p>

        <?php if ($_SESSION['vimeo_state'] == 'start'): ?>
        <p>Click the link to go to Vimeo to authorize your account.</p>
        <p><a href="<?= $authorize_link ?>"><?php echo $authorize_link ?></a></p>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($ticket): ?>
        <pre><?php print_r($ticket) ?></pre>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($videos): ?>
        <pre><?php print_r($videos) ?></pre>
        <?php endif ?>

        </body>
        </html>
```

But i got a issue.I don't know whats is error my code.Kindly check and help me.

```
        Warning: scandir(./cache,./cache): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\vimeo.php on line 290

        Warning: scandir(./cache): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\vimeo.php on line 290

        Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\vimeo.php on line 290

        Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\vimeo.php on line 291

        Notice: Undefined index: clear in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\index.php on line 10

        Notice: Undefined index: oauth_access_token in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\index.php on line 18

        Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\index.php on line 21

        Notice: Undefined index: oauth_access_token in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\index.php on line 26

        Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\index.php on line 37

        Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token_secret in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\index.php on line 38

        Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\index.php on line 42
        Vimeo Advanced API OAuth Example

        This is a basic example of Vimeo's new OAuth authentication method. Everything is saved in session vars, so click here if you want to start over.

        Click the link to go to Vimeo to authorize your account.

        http://vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=&permission=write


        Notice: Undefined variable: ticket in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\index.php on line 93

        Notice: Undefined variable: videos in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\index.php on line 97
```

Comment: [290] $vimeo->enableCache(phpVimeo::CACHE_FILE, './cache', 300);
 - >seems that the directory "phpVimeo::CACHE_FILE, './cache' " doesn't exists or lack of permissions.

Comment: Yes,Thanks for your  response,I create cache folder for there i got a issues there,

Comment: According to the errors the folder doesn't exist or there are no permissions. What is the path to that folder?

Comment: That folder is cache

Comment: What its path? Where is it located?

Comment: now i got a issue        Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\index.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token_secret in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\index.php on line 38

Notice: Undefined index: oauth_token in D:\xampp\htdocs\vimeo\index.php on line 42

Comment: its located from my root folder

Comment: xampp/htdocs/vimeo